# Cab company in Boston with child car seats?

Tags: children, taxis, boston, child-safety-seats

Is there a taxi/car service company in Boston which can provide a child car seat, if we request one in advance? We realize that the T is usually very convenient and that's what we'll mostly be using, but there are a couple of times when a cab will be useful and we won't have a car seat along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately, the family-friendly website FamilesGoTravel.com [has this](http://www.familiesgotravel.com/planning/taxi-cab-companies/):

> Here is a list of Taxi companies who have told us they have car seats.
>   We recommend you call ahead to confirm they’ll have one available to
>   you.

And their company for Boston:

**[PlanetTran](http://www.planettran.com/)**

888-756-8876

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of cab companies who provide infant / regular / booster seats as per you requirement. Boston ground transporation authority and boston police both have clear rules about the safety of child passengers and a child seat is mandatory.
Here are some site that provide child seats in Boston and family transport for upto 7 people.

- [Boston Airport Shuttle Company](https://bostonairportshuttle.com/) - 71 COMMERCIAL STREET, BOSTON, MA 02109 Phone no : 617-301-8900
- [Boston Airport Express](https://bostonairportexpress.com/) : 402 RINDGE AVE, CAMBRIDGE, MA, 02140 ~ Phone no : 617-499-1919

Answer (score 1):

Yes, off course there are lots of Cab companies in Boston and its near about areas which provide  a child car seat and also wheelchair accessible cabs. Here i suggest you [Cambridge cabs ma](http://www.cambridgecabsma.com/) company which provide pick-up and drop-off services from Boston airport. You can just call them or book your cab online in advance.

Comment: Hi, are you related to this company? Plus, it is not mentioned on the website that there are child seats available.